# Interest calculator on Python

Tags: python-3.x, math

I know that this has been asked already, but I'm having trouble with how I should implement this so I'm asking here.

My python code so far is:

```
def calculate():
    p = 10000 # dollars
    n = 12 # months
    r = 8 # interest %
    t = float(raw_input("Type the number of year that the money will be compounded for:"))
    b = p * r
    a = b ** t
    print(a)

calculate()
```

[Math formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGXFJ.png)

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. That being said the formula is very straight forward, I fail to see what problem you have

Comment: It looks like you didn't really attempt to implement the formula. You seem to be computing `(p*r)**t` which has little to do with the `A = P*(1+r/n)**(n*t)` that you give. You should make sure that you understand the formula before trying to implement it in code.

Comment: Yeah, apperently formulas are not really my thing when it comes to them in no matter where, just math or programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like John Coleman mentioned in the comments you didn't implement the formula at all.
In your code you just multiplied `p` with `r` and `b` to the power of `t`.
The right formula looks like this: `p*(1+(r/n))**(n*t)`.
I would recommend you to read an article related to python basic operators you can find one on [Python Course](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_operators.php).

```
def calculate():
    p = 10000
    n = 12
    r = .08
    t = float(input("Type the number of year that the money will be compounded for:"))
    formula = p*(1+(r/n))**(n*t)
    return formula

print (calculate())
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to return a value since you are writing a function. I would say input all your values into the function directly like so:

```
def calculate(P, r, n , t):
    exponent = n*t
    parends = 1 + (r/n)
    val = parends ** exponent
    ans = P * val
    return ans

print(calculate(10000, .08, 12, 1))
```

I would check out other resources to learn how to use functions. Codeacademy is a good one.

Here is the function just not broken into pieces:

```
def shorter(P, r, n, t):
    return P*(1+(r/n))**(n*t)

print(shorter(10000, .08, 12, 1))
```